# Deploy Play 2 App to JBoss 7

Tags: playframework-2.0, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy a Play (2.0.4) app to a JBoss AS 7.1.0 without success for the last couple of days.

I have utilised the [Play2WarPlugin](https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin/) and have followed the description.
(welcome root is disabled, war is renamed to ROOT.war, etc). However, I get the following
error when deploying

```
14:38:41,625 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "ROOT.war"
14:38:49,521 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/javax.mail.mail-1.4.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:38:49,525 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/content/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.serializer-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:38:49,526 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/content/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:38:49,527 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/content/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:38:49,528 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/content/ROOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan.xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
14:38:49,566 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "ROOT.war"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [classes.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [classes.jar:1.6.0_35]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [classes.jar:1.6.0_35]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018031: Conflict occurred processing web fragment in JAR: com.github.play2war.play2-war-core_2.9.1-0.5.jar
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarMetaDataProcessor.deploy(WarMetaDataProcessor.java:292)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unresolved conflict on servlet class: play.core.server.servlet30.Play2Servlet
at org.jboss.metadata.merge.web.spec.ServletMetaDataMerger.augment(ServletMetaDataMerger.java:93)
at org.jboss.metadata.merge.web.spec.ServletsMetaDataMerger.augment(ServletsMetaDataMerger.java:35)
at org.jboss.metadata.merge.web.spec.WebCommonMetaDataMerger.augment(WebCommonMetaDataMerger.java:313)
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WarMetaDataProcessor.deploy(WarMetaDataProcessor.java:290)
... 6 more

14:38:49,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ROOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"ROOT.war\""}}
14:38:49,653 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 74ms
14:38:49,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "ROOT.war"

14:38:49,658 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"ROOT.war\""}}}}
```

I am not sure if the warnings are the thing that is causing the failure or something else.
So my question is: 
*Do you have any suggestions and tips, what might be causing the error and how it can be resolved?*

Comment: Not really an answer, but have you tried using JBoss AS 7.1.1 instead?

Comment: Yes, I have. Under 7.1.1 it works but I need 7.1.0 as dumb as it sounds. I have found some workarounds, but the initial problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was that the bundled play2war plugin version was wrong. From the logs you can see that it tries to use 0.5 but in order to deploy to jboss 7.1.1, one needs v0.8 because of the servlet 3.0 container.

As soon as the configuration is done correctly, the deployment worked out.